# Erro - Java Maven Não Compila - Release Version Not Supported

Tags: java, maven

Boa tarde pessoal,

Instalei sozinha o intellij no ubuntu versão 18.4. Preciso fazer um projeto Maven. Fiz um teste, criei o projeto e dentro uma classe para fazer um simples Hello world. No entanto só aparece esse erro da foto e não retorna o Hello world, alguém poderia me ajudar ?

Obrigada [Erro que aparece na tela esta na imagem]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poste o código em formato de texto e se possível,coloque o erro também ,sugiro que você leia https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8089/guia-de-sobreviv%c3%aancia-do-sopt-vers%c3%a3o-curta?cb=1 e edite seu post para que ele não seja fechado.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O problema está na versão do Java que você está utilizando para a compilação no Maven.

Você pode corrigir isso de duas formas:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>    
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source> <!-- Identificar a versão desejada aqui -->
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Ou:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Estas instruções acima são equivalentes.

Sugiro também utilizar a última versão disponível do plugin, atualmente é a `3.8.1`.

---

A partir do Java 9, deve-se utilizar `release` ao invés de `source` e `target`, como abaixo:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>    
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <release>11</release>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

---

Se você estiver utilizando [Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-automatic-expansion-maven), você pode apenas identificar a versão do Java através da propriedade `java.version`:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: muito obrigada pela ajuda :)

Comment: que bom que deu certo @FabíCanedoYugar :) não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita e dar upvote :)